# How do I create many-many association in feathers-sequelize?

Tags: javascript, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I have a feathers api set up using feathers-sequelize to persist to a MySQL database.

I've got the datamodel set up and can see the relevant tables are created.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');

  const orders = sequelizeClient.define('orders', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4

  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate (models) {
          this.belongsToMany(models.users, {through: "offers", foreignKey: "orderId", otherKey: "userId"});
      }
    }
  });

  return orders;
};
```

How do I actually create an association of `offers`? I've tried something like this:

```
const orders = hook.app.service("orders");

order.offers.push(user.id);
orders.patch(order.id, order);
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to patch with a many-to-many. Simply use the [Sequelize association method](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#associating-objects):

```
order.addUser(user.id)
```

To return the association you might need to do an `order.reaload()` in your after hook.